# CentOS 7 Cloudflare Full SSL 521 Error?

Tags: centos, ssl, centos7, cloudflare

Alright, so I'm trying to use WHMCS and in order to run on https I have to have my SSL set to Full in CloudFlare. This would be fine if the site didn't crash. It works fine if I connect directly to the IP, but when I connect via the domain name it doesn't work. I get a 521 server error.

I am using CentOS 7 and I installed firewalld. I whitelisted the IP addresses that CloudFlare has.

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
public
sources: 173.245.48.0/20 103.21.244.0/22 103.22.200.0/22 103.31.4.0/22 141.101.64.0/18 108.162.192.0/18 188.114.96.0/20 197.234.240.0/22 198.41.128.0/17 162.158.0.0/15 104.16.0.0/12 172.64.0.0/13 131.0.72.0/22
```

These are all the IPs listed on Cloudflare's website. I have tried rebooting the firewall, rebooting Apache, and even rebooting the server and I still get a 521 error. What am I missing? I have tried everything on their help page that can be seen here: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171916-Error-521-Web-server-is-down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFlare currently offers four TLS / SSL settings:
 - Off
 - Flexible
 - Full
 - Full Strict

Given your comment that it works when you switch to Flexible makes me think that you do not have a certificate set up on your own server.
Flexible means cloudflare is connecting to your server over unencrypted http.

Since you stated that WHMCS requires Full, cloudflare in that mode connects to your server over https, but therefore requires a certificate on your server:
"[..] before enabling Full SSL option, configure your origin web server to allow HTTPS connections on port 443 and present either a self-signed SSL certificate, a Cloudflare Origin CA certificate, or a valid certificate purchased from a Certificate Authority."

It's explained on this article: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170416-End-to-end-encryption-with-Cloudflare-Part-3-SSL-options